# Generating and Sending a Follow Up Email after 14 Days of Quoting from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, email, outlook

I'm looking at automatically generating and sending an email to customers after 14 days of quoting for a job.
We run our database in SQL Server and know where the data is stored, but we are stuck at the email automation.

This is for acquiring more customers and work from people we have already quoted for.

```
USE [Clarity]
GO

SELECT [reference]
      ,[status]
      ,[description]
      ,[quotedDate]
      ,[QuotationRequiredDate]
      ,[ExpiryDate]
  FROM [dbo].[Quotation]
GO
```

Comment: Welcome. You are telling us what you are expecting, but your code makes no attempt to solve it. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you need to attempt the task before you can have an issue with it requiring help. It may just be a simple case of use. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wasn't asking for someone to write the code for me, i put a general question out there for help to be pointed in the right direction; not to be criticised.

Comment: You can use database mail to send those emails. In you stored procedure, you get the customers need to be followed up and call the database mail to send the email. You can create a sql agent job to run your stored procedure daily.

Comment: @BenMelling In that case, a daily `cron` job launching a process to:  1) get from db filtering by QuotationRequiredDate, 2) fill an email template for each user, 3) send these emails, will do the trick.